# Node.JS + socket.io + IIS = ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, sockets, iis, socket.io

I am running a SSL socket on port 8081. While this works perfectly with Apache2.4, after a while on IIS, socket.io crashes with ECONNRESET, which never happens with Apache. My socket.io version is 1.3.7. IIS is v10 (windows server 2016).

I've added some error handling as recommended but it does not solve the issue. Here is a sanitized code.

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('example.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('example.cert'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('example.inter')
};

var app = require('https').createServer(options),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);  
io.set('origins', '*:8081');
app.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
});
app.listen(8081);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(__socket) {

     __socket.on('error', function(){
          __socket.destroy();
     });

     __socket.on('disconnect', function(){
          __socket.destroy();
     });
}
```

[I read](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9845#issuecomment-264032107) that you can fix that by adding ciphers like

```
ciphers: 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
```

but I do not know how relevant it is to my code and even where to put that!

Here is the detail of the error

```
{ Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:285:23)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

**edit:** updated to latest version (2.0.3) and still having the issue.

**edit2:** It appears ECONNERESET happens when using **io.emit** which is weird because it feels like it tries to emit without verifying that the socket is still connected first...

Comment: Just to be clear, is your IIS acting as a reverse proxy in front of your node app? If so, is there a particular reason you are using ssl for the comunications between IIS and Node?

Comment: No. IIS runs on 443. Node/Socketio runs SSL on 8081

Comment: What is the link between IIS and Node then? IIS is just serving the page that connects to the soket.io app?

Comment: That is right, it only serves the page.

Comment: It might be a good idea to expose the Node app thru IIS (acting as a reverse proxy). To avoid CORS. Also, in that scenario (IIS not being involved whith the node app at all), i don't see how it could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am guessing you are on right track with the ciphers because I read that the Cipher Suites at the Group Policy of the server causes HTTPS Connection Reset as in https://forums.iis.net/t/1234599.aspx?IIS+7+The+connection+was+reset+error+on+HTTPS

Comment: Just to verify, do you have iisnode installed on the windows server?

Comment: No, IIS NODE IS NOT INSTALLED

Comment: @Eric did you ever figure out why this happened or what the solution was?

Answer (score 4):

I think that there are issues with IIS WebSockets implementations while hosting node.js applications as mentioned in an article I came across from Tomasz Janczuk - [Hosting socket.io WebSocket Apps in IIS using iisnode](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html).

There is a section about configuring IIS with a web.config file and Janczuk mentions that there is a conflict with the shipped WebSocket in IIS and node.js WebSocket implementation.

I also looked at the WebSocket setting that was introduced in IIS 8 and there have been no modifications through IIS 10.

I suggest trying to disable the IIS WebSocket setting as mentioned in Janczuks article with a web.config for IIS.

```
<WebSocket enabled="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that and report

Comment: So this won't work as I don't even have the websocket role/feature enabled in IIS.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A VALID ANSWER THIS IS AN AUTOMATED VALIDATION. NONE OF THE ANSWERS PROVIDED WORK.

Comment: @Eric you mentioned that you are not using iis node and therefore you will likely have issues running node in iis as most of the research I've done has mentioned as well. I would setup iis node as per the article I linked to and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Again, I am not using Web sockets from IIS, and it is not running on any port IIS is running. On paper these two don't talk and don't see each other.

Comment: Even if you are accessing the node application directly you are still passing through IIS which can cause issues on it's own. IIS node helps manage the interruption IIS could potentially cause. I believe this is the case in most situations.

Comment: As I have mentionned: Both Node and IIS are running on different ports. IIS and Node do not talk to each other. IIS doesn't even have websocket installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('example.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('example.cert'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('example.inter'),
  ciphers: 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
};
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/certsimple/ssl-config)

Comment: It usually happens at least once a day so I will post back tomorrow. Thinking I didn't even try to put the ciphers in the options, silly me...